# phpMyAdmin freezing on SQL and Import tabs

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running phpMyAdmin-4.7.2-all-languages on two servers, one local WAMP, the other remote LAMP. Both phpMyAdmin's are byte-for-byte identical installations (with exception of the auth type, config for local, cookie for remote). Both have been running perfectly for ages. A few days ago I tried to insert some data in an existing table using the SQL tab. I got the yellow/orange "Loading" popup, then ... nothing. It just stopped responding. No error messages, not even a console error that makes any sense. So, I try the Import tab, put the data in a file, and got the same lock up. Tried the same thing on the local server and it worked fine.

I can enter some simple command like "SELECT * FROM 'table'" and this locks up, too. Nothing works through the SQL tab. I don't think it's even seeing the commands and data I'm sending.

So, the SQL and Import tabs lock up on the remote server only. SQL and Import tabs work 100% on the local server. Everything else works perfectly on both servers - I can browse the tables, change the structures, etc. with no problems whatsoever. BTW, the data I'm trying to import is not large at all, just a couple 1000 records and a simple structure.

I have tried it on a tablet computer, IE11, FireFox, and Chrome, all with the same results. I have run mysql_upgrade, verified user permissions (all), verified SSL certs, and googled every similar complaint for the last several days. I've even starting looking for an alternative to phpMyAdmin. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Try doing issuing similar commands from the command line to see if you have any problem with database functionality. If so, then PHPMyAdmin is not really the problem.

Comment: no, i don't think that's the issue. the server seems to be functioning 100%. Whatever the issue, it seems to be centered on phpmyadmin, and perhaps on the type of html transactions involved.

Comment: Try adminer then.

Comment: thanks, did not know that existed.  It might be a good temp work-around, but i would much rather solve the problem with phpmyadmin. BTW - i tried turning off all protection software, ad blockers, etc... No change.

Comment: I've never had any trouble with PHP my admin so I'm not sure what it could be. Are you sure you're using the latest version? Could it be you're using a version of PHP that's <5.3?

Comment: Neither have I, and I've been using it for a long time. That's why I believe this deserves the attention of the user community (not just downvotes). I was using 4.6.4 when the problem first occurred, so i updated to 4.7.2 hoping that would solve the problem. The latest version had exactly the same issue, though. (server is 5.5.56). Of course, I don't expect the culprit to be phpmyadmin **alone**. Like most complex system faults, this will turn out to be a concurrence of at least two issues, which singly would not have been significant. That is, provided an answer is achieved.

Comment: I don't know why it's getting a down vote either (I gave you an up vote just now). I guess maybe because it's not a programming question per se.

Upgrade your PHP to at least 5.6.x and see if that changes it.

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.30. not all SO topics have to be 100% programming...

Comment: I'm not sure what else to tell you. Did you see any errors in the PHP log? Are you logging MySQL errors? Short of digging around in the system myself, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: no errors. i can produce a similar behavior by inserting a php die into server_sql.php. it's as if the code was exiting without giving a clue as to why.

Comment: You may have to turn on SQL error logging.

Comment: that's server side. as expected, no errors. the problem is client side. no data from the sql form is getting to the server.

Comment: another tough question with no answers